Как сделать уникальное имя сохраняемого документа VBA excel. Например Test0, Test1 и тд
Public Sub ButtonSave_Click()
Workbooks.Add
FiNum = 0
FiName = "C:\Users\svv71\Desktop\Test\Test" & FiNum & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FiName
FiNum = FiNum + 1

ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub


А в чём, собственно, вопрос?

Как должен работать ваш код, по вашим ожиданиям, и как он работает на самом деле? Если выдаёт ошибку, то приведите её текст и укажите место, на котором произошла остановка.

В каком множестве имён должна быть уникальность?

Примерно так:
Sub sxfgsdf()
  Dim FiNum As Integer, FiName As String
  FiName = "C:\Users\svv71\Desktop\Test\Test"
  While Dir(FiName & FiNum & ".xlsx") <> ""
    FiNum = FiNum + 1 ' циклим и инкрементируем, пока такой файл есть
  Wend
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename := FiName & FiNum & ".xlsx"
End Sub

Если вам нужно вообще уникальное имя, то его нужно сохранять где-то в книге. Можно сделать новый лист Misc (например) и скрыть его.
Sub sxfgsdf()
  Dim FiNum As Integer, FiName As String
  FiName = "C:\Users\svv71\Desktop\Test\Test"
  FiNum = Sheets("Misc").Cells(1, 1) + 1
  While Dir(FiName & FiNum & ".xlsx") <> ""
    FiNum = FiNum + 1 ' циклим и инкрементируем, пока такой файл есть
  Wend
  Sheets("Misc").Cells(1, 1) = FiNum ' счётчик будет в последней сохранённой книге
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename := FiName & FiNum & ".xlsx"
End Sub

Автономно счётчик можно хранить в отдельном файле.

Почему-то в цикл нету захода при отладке. Поэтому и не работает. Хотя в while должно всегда заходить)

В while должно заходить только при выполнении условия. Если не заходит, значит такого файла нет и можно сохранять книгу. Процедура выше обеспечивает сохранение книги на диске с уникальным именем. Или вам нужно что-то другое?

Спасибо за ответ! Нет, мне не надо совсем уникального имени, нужно чтобы работал код. А он не работает. Пробую запустить ваш 1й вариант. Условие, прописанное в while должно всегда выполняться, поскольку путь не пустая строка всегда, но в отладке в цикл нет захода и код не работает, почему не знаю.

Фукция DIr с параметрами выдаёт полное имя файла, если найдены совпадения с маской или именем, и пустую строку, если совпадений нет. Таким образом проверяется наличие файла с выбранным именем на диске. Если такого файла нет, то в цикл не входит, и книга запысывается. Если есть совпадения, то в цикле переменная инкрементируется, а цикл выполняется, пока есть совпадения.

Спасибо за пояснения и код, всё работает!

Вариант с использованием CustomDocumentProperties
Option Explicit

Sub UniqNameSave()
    Const CDP_NAME = "Version", BASE_NAME = "Test*.xlsx"
    Dim Version As Object
    With ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Version = .Item(CDP_NAME) ' пытаемся извлечь свойство с номером версии книги
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Version Is Nothing Then ' если свойства еще нет, то добавляем его и устанавливаем начальное значение
            .Add Name:=CDP_NAME, LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeNumber, Value:=0
        Else
            Version = Version + 1 ' если свойство уже существует, инкрементируем
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(BASE_NAME, "*", Format(Version, "000")) ' сохраняем книгу, добавляя номер версии из свойства и форматируя
    End With
End Sub

Test016.xlsx
Test015.xlsx
Test014.xlsx
Test013.xlsx
Test012.xlsx
...

